# Change fragment in viewpager 2 on activity launch and not on orientation change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I am creating an app where I am using viewpager2. when the activity is launched the viewpager page is set based on some data from the previous activity. which i did by using

```
viewpager2.setcurrentItem(index , true)
```

in oncreate method.

#### Problem

Suppose the user opens the viewpagerActivity. veiwpager with index 2 is displayed.
Now the user swipes to index 3.
Now the user performs orientation change.
The user is again taken to index 2.

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: so save the index somewhere and apply it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it in `onCreate`, use bundle to check if it's `null`, if `yes` it is fresh launch else orientation change.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        viewpager2.setcurrentItem(index , true)
    }
}
```